# Joomla3 template is unreadable

Tags: joomla, localhost, joomla-k2

I have just uploaded my Joomla 3.1 template from local host to the server..

but I found a problem to use my customized template... I just get a blank page but it works when I change the template to one of joomla default template... I cleaned the cache and I am sure that configuration.php is all right...
I can access my joomla control panel and when I click to edit my template I just got the same blank page...
it seems that my template is not readable by the server... any one could help please?

I'm using Gantry and K2 btw.

this is the joomla site
http://aqaratelmasria.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between uploading and installing.

A template is considered an extensions and thus MUST be installed

You have 2 options, you can either:

1. Zip the template up and install it properly....or
2. You can [Discover](http://docs.joomla.org/Help25%3aExtensions_Extension_Manager_Discover) it. Discovering basically detects extensions that haven't gone though the normal install process.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

A [quick search of StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjoomla%5D%20blank%20page) shows, that when you get a blank page in PHP applications, like Joomla, it means:

1. There is a php error.
2. PHP error reporting is turned off.

To determine what the error is login to the `/administrator` section of your website and navigate to `Global Configuration` then select the `Server` tab and turn up the `Error Reporting` level, it's probably on `None`.

*You may also want to go to the `System` tab and set the `Debug System` switch to `Yes` for additional information.*

Then try and access your site again, this time you should see the error that's causing your problem.